# Webpack - warn when import is undefined / not declared

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

Is there a way to get a warning/error message when imports are undefined, i.e. not declared in a file that I am importing from?

```
// file1.js
export const var1 = 'var1'

// file2.js
import { var2 } from './file1'

var2() // this will throw an error
```

How to solve this issue?

I am using webpack in version 3.11.0

Comment: First, what is your scenario? Because this is a perfect example of the "compiler" helping you out.

Comment: I've moved like ~300files and want to make sure every import works correctly

Comment: Would this really makes sense? If you are trying to import something that does not exists, it would break when the code tries to get required anyways.

Comment: It doesn't break when the code tries to get required. It breakes when the code gets executed - unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`module.strictExportPresence`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-contexts):

```js
{
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true
  }
}
```